# What is the AMD equivalent of Intel’s Node Manager

Tags: central-processing-unit, redfish

I’m looking to better understand server telemetry. On all platforms Intel currently provides more robust telemetry with a separate on-dye processor called node manager:

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/intel-power-node-manager-v3-spec.pdf

I assume AMD has an equivalent capability but I’m not sure what it is called

Edit: Adding redfish tag because I’m specifically curious about redfish telemetry pulls leveraging this capability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked another engineer and the answer is there isn’t which is why in AMD’s telemetry system you only get CPU usage. That is being pulled from the proc itself but there is no separate on-dye device from which to pull information. There likely will be (is?) one in future generations but it will take time for the vendors to implement the hooks to pull the data when AMD does bring one in.

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience of it myself but I think what you're looking for falls within AMD's DASH systems/protocols - had a quick google around and found a range of things, maybe do the same?